# Limit text in a cell only to the penultimate bar found

Tags: regex, url, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

The links are made up of a different number of bars, but what contains between the last bar and the penultimate does not interest me, what formula could I use?

Original:

```
https://int.soccerway.com/national/czech-republic/czech-liga/20192020/championship-round/r54505/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/championship/20192020/regular-season/r53782/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/finland/veikkausliiga/2020/regular-season/r56520/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/germany/play-offs-12/20192020/s17666/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/germany/play-offs-23/20192020/s17670/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/norway/1-division/2020/regular-season/r56858/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/sweden/superettan/2020/s18293/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/united-states/nwsl-challenge-cup/2020/preliminary-round/r58293/
```

Expected Result:

```
https://int.soccerway.com/national/czech-republic/czech-liga/20192020/championship-round/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/england/championship/20192020/regular-season/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/finland/veikkausliiga/2020/regular-season/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/germany/play-offs-12/20192020/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/germany/play-offs-23/20192020/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/norway/1-division/2020/regular-season/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/sweden/superettan/2020/
https://int.soccerway.com/national/united-states/nwsl-challenge-cup/2020/preliminary-round/
```

Test Fail:

```
REGEXEXTRACT('Página1'!T2:T,
REGEXREPLACE('Página1'!T2:T,"(https?:\/\/([\w.-]+\/){6})","($1)"))
```

The model I tested did not work because the penultimate bar is not always in position 6, so it does not work for my need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the last text and `/` and capture all before in group 1.

In the replacement use group 1.

For example a single entry `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(https?://\S+/)[^\s/]+/", "$1")`

```
(https?://\S+/)[^\s/]+/
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6IWI6J/1)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "(.+)/"), "(.+)/")))
```

[image: 0]